# Connection refused: When I try to send email from my linode server

Tags: django, vps, linode, django-email

I have a django project and for email settings I use my personal gmail account. It works just fine when Im testing from localhost. But i get "conection refused error" from django when I try from my linode vps. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation on my site; it turned out to be another error inside my application in the generation of the email.

In this case, hopefully this has been solved, but you should check your SMTP server logs to verify that the project is connecting to SMTP. If it isn't check the `EMAIL_*` settings in your `settings.py` file. If it is, but then immediately disconnecting, I'd bet there's something failing in the building of your email (that is, in the parsing of the arguments to your `send_mail` function).